# mysql - get max and min values of column grouped by day with 2 hour offset (i.e., 1/19/23 2AM - 1/20/23 2AM), not midnight to midnight

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a max value and min value in a 24 hour period (2AM-2AM) grouped by power meter box identifier (essentially a serial number) in mysql.

I'm beating my head against a wall here. No matter what I try to do when I try grouping by day with an offset of X hours (in this example 2 - and I've tried many of the stack overflow solutions to no avail), it's still grouping from midnight to midnight.

```
select  power_box, max(reading), min(reading)
    from meters
    GROUP BY 
        year(date_add(from_unixtime(eventTime/1000), interval -2 hour)),
        month(date_add(from_unixtime(eventTime/1000), interval -2 hour)),
        day(date_add(from_unixtime(eventTime/1000), interval -2 hour)), 
        power_box
    ;
```

Any SQL experts out there to help?

The grouping is still midnight to midnight - can't figure this out!

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work, but I think you can simplify it to just `GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(..., INTERVAL 2 HOURS))`

Comment: Also `GROUP BY FLOOR((eventTime - 7200000)/86400000)`

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? Can you add sample input, the desired result, and the actual result?

Comment: You don't return the date in the `SELECT` list. How can you tell how it's grouping?